# X-Ray transparent material

Tags: experimental-physics, material-science

I am looking for a material which is fully transparent to X-rays.

In addition, it should be solid enough to serve as a substrate on which I will deposit some biomolecules.

Comment: This article may be of use to you. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3121300/